# SAPI Speech Recognition - How to create and delete recognition profiles using SpeechLib

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

SAPI documentation cover the creation and deletion of a recognition profile. But how can I do it with `SpeechLib`? I would like to:

1. Find the currently active profile, and keep a note of it.
2. Create a new profile.
3. Make the new profile the active one.

When exiting my app:

4. Delete the profile that I have created.
5. Set back the active profile to what it was before launching my app.

BTW: Is `SpeechLib` documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpeechLib documentation is found by looking for [SAPI Automation interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720592(v=vs.85).aspx).

Profiles are a type of [SpObjectToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722587(v=vs.85).aspx), and can be enumerated using the [SpObjectTokenCategory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722587(v=vs.85).aspx) object.  Specifically, create a new SpObjectToken, and set the ID, then use EnumerateTokens to get the profiles.  (This example uses VB, but you should be able to translate)

```
Dim E As SpeechLib.ISpeechObjectTokens      'an enumeration of object tokens
Dim C As SpeechLib.SpObjectTokenCategory    'a category of object tokens    
Set C = New SpObjectTokenCategory
C.SetId SpeechCategoryRecoProfiles
List1.AddItem "   " & C.Id
Set E = C.EnumerateTokens()

For Each T In E
    List1.AddItem "   " & T.GetDescription
Next
```

Comment: OK, but after creating SpObjectToken, how can I make it a "new" installed profile, so it will appear in the Control Panel with its own name?

Comment: Set the description using `SpObjectToken.DataKey.SetStringValue(NULL, szDescription)`.

Comment: I first have to set its category, and MyNewProfile.Category.SetId(SpeechStringConstants.SpeechCategoryRecoProfiles) throws an error.

Comment: You want [`MyNewProfile.SetId(NULL, SpeechStringConstants.SpeechCate‌​goryRecoProfiles, TRUE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722624(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It's weird, the compiler accept only two arguments: `SetId(Id as String, [CreateIfNotExist as Boolean=Flase])`. Using three arguments does not compile, and using only two throws a runtime exception. I'm using it with VB.NET, if relevant.

Comment: What version of VS and Windows are you using?   I imported "Microsoft Speech Object Library" into a fresh VB project (using VS 2015), and the object browser shows ISpObjectToken with a 3-argument SetId method.

Comment: I will check that. Thanks.